# JSlint error selectedDate already defined

Tags: javascript, jslint

When I run JSlint on this piece of code I get this error

> Error: Problem at line 25 character 26: 'selectedDate' is already
>   defined. var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
>
> Implied global: $ 1,4,13,14,26,27,28,31,33,34,42, updateSelects
>   13,19,21

http://jsfiddle.net/bzPYg/

I think it is referring to this code

```
'dateSelected', function(e, selectedDate, $td, state) {
    updateSelects(selectedDate);
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error sort of explains itself.

> Problem at line 25 character 26: 'selectedDate' is already defined.
>   var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);

You are declaring the variable selectedDate again, and you are filling it with a new Date object taking in the value of the original variable selectedDate. You should rename the variable to something else.

```
var date = new Date(selectedDate);
```

And just to note the error is occuring here:

```
var updateSelects = function(selectedDate) {
   var selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate);
   ...
});
```

Comment: This is called *variable shadowing* and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11963373/451969) gives a decent explanation.

Comment: Thanks I changed the slectedDate to selectDate and JSlint doesnt give me any errors any more. So thanks.