# Function's scope of variables

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I execute function like this:

```
var a = 123;
function f() { 
  alert(a);
  var a = 9;
} 
f();
```

the result is `undefined`, why this happened? Why it's not `123`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope
What happens is the interpreter knows that `a` is defined within the scope of `f`, just not at the point where you call `alert()`. Hence `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript variable is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963240/javascript-variable-is-undefined)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function is actually compiled as:

```
function f() {
  var a; 
  alert(a);
  a = 9;
}
```

because of variable hoisting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

So your function redeclares `a` as a local variable with the value as `undefined`, `alert`s it, and then re-sets its value to `9`.

At the time of the `alert`, its value is `undefined` because of the hoisting.

Comment: but if I remove the `var a = 9;`, the alert could show correctly `123`, why it doesn't  redeclares `a`?

Comment: @hh54188 If you remove `var a = 9;`, then there is no redeclaration...you removed it...all your function will be is `alert(a);`. So it looks up the scope chain and finds `a` in the global scope as `123`, so it's evaluated as `123`.

Comment: but the redeclare was happened after the `alert`, so this means the variable declare is doesn't matter with exetute order?

Comment: @hh54188 Right, but if you read my answer, it explains that the variable declaration was **hoisted** (read the website link I provided too). Technically, your function is **technically** executed as the function I included in my answer, because of hoisting. So `a` is **technically** redefined at the beginning of the function (before the `alert`)

Answer (score 0):

If you declare `a` in a function syntax again that becomes a new variable. If you want to use the previous value 123 then you should not have included the `var a = 9` statement, since it creates a new variable.
This may explain in detail :
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope)