# Why would my global variable be undefined in the minified version of my javascript file?

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a variable

```
var globalValue = 700;
```

declared at the top of my aScript.js script file, this variable is being accessed by another function aFunction() in the same file.

While everything works fine normally, when i minify my script files, the value of globalValue inside aFunction() is undefined.

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: just do a `;` before the declaration. It could be that the previous file it is appending to is not ended properly. This would ensure your declaration is independent of the previous lines of code.

Comment: @karthikr What would that do? Do you know why this happens?

Comment: What minifier are you using? Can show us the relevant part of the minified code?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen YUI Compressor

Comment: Are you combining files as well? I find it hard to believe there would be such a bug in YUI, check your process the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I don't have any other variable by that name in any other script files. I don't see what mistake I could be making here. I have global variables in other js files and they seem to persist fine, but I can't get my head around why only this one particular script file would have this issue.

Comment: Did you try prepending the `;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the culprit here. Another script file had an error(which I couldn't control because it was an in-house script written by someone else), which we were ignoring at the moment because it was very insignificant.

The order in which i had declared the files for minifying was -

```
<JavaScriptFiles Include= "Scripts/theScriptWithError.js" />
<JavaScriptFiles Include= "Scripts/aScript.js" />
```

So now, because of the error in theScriptWithError.js, it wasn't loading my variables from aScript.js. I moved the order so that

```
<JavaScriptFiles Include= "Scripts/aScript.js" />
<JavaScriptFiles Include= "Scripts/theScriptWithError.js" />
```

and it's all working fine now.

That was the reason for all the chaos. Thanks for your suggestions and help with this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064947/javascript-confuse-about-functions-scope-of-variables) same problem is explained. You defined `globalValue` as global variable. But when you minified your code, within `aFunction()` function you also defined `globalValue` as local variable (maybe because of minifier), like that:

```
var globalValue = 700;
function aFunction() {
  var globalValue;
  alert(globalValue); // undefined
}
aFunction();
```

Comment: We don't know if that's his problem or not. (And it's probably not, since he'd see the same problem in non-minified code).

Comment: He said `While everything works fine normally, when i minify my script files, the value of globalValue inside aFunction() is undefined`. So problem occured after minifing.

Comment: Sure, but it wouldn't do this. The YUI minification wouldn't insert random variables into his functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth looking through the minified version for the declaration line. I suspect what is happening is that the minifier has helpfully shortened the variable name in the declaration (to something like _a1) but not replaced all occurences of globalValue within aFunction.

I've seen this before with similar minifiers but I'm afraid I never got to the bottom of why - rather I found a correctly minified version ofthe script online.